# Add water pump to outdoor fountain

Tags: wiring, outdoor

Right now the question is how to run power to the pump.

I have an outdoor fountain about 10 to 15 feet away from an outdoor outlet. In between the outlet and the fountain is a brick patio.

The thing is a mosquito breeding ground, so I added some mosquito dunks and want to add a water pump to cycle the water (the fountain has two levels - bottom level sits in the ground).

At first I thought about just plugging an extension cord to the pump, but I'm concerned about exposing the connection to the elements. Some people told me to just wrap the connection to the pump with duct/electrical tape. Not sure about that...

So, how should I get power to the pump without spending money on getting an electrician to run power underground to an outdoor outlet next to the fountain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting an outdoor extension cord for this.

[image]

The cord is used for stuff like powering Christmas decorations and the like, and has a cover to shield the outlets from the elements.